# Scala io.source fromFile

Tags: scala

I have this two lines(among the all others)

```
import scala.io.Source

val source = Source.fromFile(filename)
```

As I understand this is a way to read file content.I have read 
http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/io/Source.html#iter:Iterator[Char]

I still do not get it what does Source.from File represent,one of Type Members,or something else?

Comment: First, the Source you referenced is abstract and has no `.fromFile()`.
You want the companion object http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/io/Source$.html

Second, source is a BufferedSource, from which you can obtain the content in many ways. http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/io/BufferedSource.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the Scala API stated [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/io/Source$.html#fromFile(name:String)(implicitcodec:scala.io.Codec):scala.io.BufferedSource) fromFile is a method defined on the `Source` companion object. This is a curried method with the first param list taking a single `String` representing the path of the file to be read and the second curried parameter list takes a single implicit codec argument of type [scala.io.Codec](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/io/Codec.html). And this function returns a [BufferedSource](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/io/BufferedSource.html) object